# Get a leaf nodes by recursive query

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a categories structure as follows

[image]

I want to select leaf node. i mean the the categories who don't have sub categories.

In my database monitor, cpu, novels and comics will be answer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit :
I tried this.

```
public function get_valid_categories($parent)
        {
                $has_childs = false;
                foreach($this->categories as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value['parent'] == $parent) {
                        if ($has_childs === false) {
                            $has_childs = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->valid_categories[] =  $value['name'];
                        }
                        $this->get_valid_categories($key);

                    }
                }
                if ($has_childs === true)
                {
                    return $this->valid_categories ;
                }
        }
```

and i m calling this function as follows

```
get_valid_categories(0);
```

Comment: Hint: select all IDs who are no parents, i.e. who are not contained in `parent_Id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a recursive query for this. How about the following SQL:

```
select t1.* 
from table t1
    left join table t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id
where t2.id is null
```

This takes the rows in your table and self-joins to get each row's children. It then filters out those rows that have no children by checking for `t2.id is null`.

Comment: +1 so silly of me that i got to search for this simple querry. Thanx it helped in my case too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are probably many possible solutions but here is the first one that came to my mind:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
WHERE id NOT IN (
                 SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id) FROM categories
                )
```

Not so elegant as using joins, but can be an alternative solution for the problem.
Hope that helps.